# binascii.unhexlify working differently in Python 3.2 and Python3.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I used to work on `Linux Mint`, and the latest version of `Python 3` embedded in it is `Python 3.4`.  My program takes a hex string as input, decodes it and creates a `bytearray` so I can decode several information using `struct.unpack`. For example:

```
hex_str = "00000E0C180E180FEABF070030313564336332363338303431653039004A62004A62006A62406A622E636F6D00"
s = binascii.unhexlify(hex_str)
print(s) # Would print b'\x00\x00\x0e\x0c\x18\x0e\x18\x0f\xea\xbf\x07\x00015d3c2638041e09\x00Jb\x00Jb\x00jb@jb.com\x00'
data = bytearray(s)
date_data = data[:9]
form_date = get_date(date_data) # Get the date using a bunch of struct.unpack
print(form_date)  # Would print '2014-12-24 14:24:15'
```

Last week my computer crashed, so I had to build a new machine. I decided to give a try to `Debian Wheezy`. However, I discovered that the only version of `Python` is `Python 2.7`. I installed `Python 3` using `apt-get`, but I noticed that the version installed is only `Python 3.2`. When I run the exact same code as above, I get a `TypeError` on the `binascii.unhexlify` line:

```
hex_str = "00000E0C180E180FEABF070030313564336332363338303431653039004A62004A62006A62406A622E636F6D00"
s = binascii.unhexlify(hex_str)
# TypeError: 'NavigableString' does not support the buffer interface
```

I don't understand this error, what does it mean?
I checked on Google but couldn't find anything: have there been any changes on `binascii.unhexlify` between the two versions? Do I have to change something in 3.2?

I really don't see how to solve this... Maybe there is a better way to achieve that?

Thanks.

PS: I could go back to `Linux Mint`, or install `Python 3.4` on `Debian`, but I think my production server is a fresh install of `Debian`, so with `Python 3.2`... so I'd better target that version (and I am glad I discovered it now!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there was a change in behavior between versions.  From the [`binascii` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html):

> **Note:** `a2b_*` functions accept Unicode strings containing only ASCII characters. Other functions only accept *bytes-like objects* (such as `bytes`, `bytearray` and other objects that support the buffer protocol).
>
> *Changed in version 3.3:* ASCII-only unicode strings are now accepted by the `a2b_*` functions.

So if you want to target Python <3.3, you need to pass in either `bytes` or `bytearray` objects instead of strings.